# netty fireWriteComplete actually nothing written to remote

Tags: java, netty, nio

netty 3.x, nio model:

the netty IO writing thread will invoke `WritableByteChannel.write(ByteBuffer)` finally,netty will consider it written successfully, but actually the bytes are written to a socket output buffer.

In some cases,the physical network link is broken,but this write operation will not throw exception,even return an integer greater than 0(mean some bytes are written),this WritableByteChannel does not detect the link broken in time. So when netty fireWriteComplete,it does not mean some bytes really written to remote.

How can i tell where some bytes are written to remote successfully?

I know heartbeat mechanism can tell when the ack of heartbeat received,but heartbeat mechanism will bring me another problem.

Answer (score 0):

To make it short ... you can't. The longer answer is to implement it in the protocol logic like send and "ack" message back if something was received.